What is the callbackUrlScheme? FlutterWebAuth2
I have a problem with using webauth2 on the Flutter. It is possible to access through url normally, but it is difficult to receive a response. I wonder if the reason is the wrong value of the callback UrlScheme or another reason. Thank you.
error message
app screen
Future<void> signIn() async {
  final url = Uri.https('kauth.kakao.com', '/oauth/authorize', {
    'client_id' : '7f8c9995a36f55554348032c83b16b96',
    'redirect_uri' : 'http://15.164.142.62:8080/login/oauth2/code/kakao',
    'response_type': 'code',
  });

  final result = await FlutterWebAuth2.authenticate(
      url: url.toString(), callbackUrlScheme : "http");


  print(result);
  final body = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters;
  print(body);
}

using flutter clean and flutter pub get command
